# Error setting up Crontab

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

Trying to set up a cronjob:

```
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases > /backups/mysql/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.sql
```

Getting error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.fuly8s":2: bad day-of-month
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

I'm not sure where the error is, any suggestions?

Comment: I have no problems adding this line to my user’s crontab using `crontab -e` on current Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error complains about line 2 of your crontab. In order to decide what the error is, we need to see this line, and preferably the complete crontab as shown in the editor.

Most likely, you removed a `#` somewhere which now causes a previous comment to be regarded as a cronjob specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding a line to crontab you need a user field. For instance:

```
0 12 * * * root /usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases > /backups/mysql/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.sql
```

Does that fix the problem?

Comment: If the OP uses a user-specific crontab (usually edited using `crontab -e`), he must not use a user field. The fact that the crontab is `installed` hints at a user-specific one rather than `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @Claudius - Yep. The question doesn't specify how he's adding the cron job though (and it looks fine for a user-specific crontab) so I am assuming he's just editing /etc/crontab.

Comment: But how would he edit `/etc/crontab` in a way that these messages are displayed? To my knowledge, changes to `/etc/crontab` take effect immediately and editing it does not occur via some temporary file in `/tmp`.

Comment: Looks like it shoulud be alright...sorry I didn't provide more info earlier.  It was edited from `crontab -e`....It accepted the new crontab now. I'll just have to wait and see if it executes properly today.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Claudius - it saves crontab to `/tmp` first to ensure the syntax is correct and there are no errors before replacing the file to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: `/etc/crontab` is not the file you edit with `crontab -e`. The file you edit with `crontab -e` is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$(whoami)`.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy - Claudius is absolutely correct and deserves the reputation for this question. (I'm +1-ing your answer Claudius)